# How to call a method from base class a few levels up in the inheritance chain?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, base-class

Assume we have following inheritance chain:

```
class Base:
    def method(self):
        # …

class Derived1(Base):
    def method(self):
        # …

class Derived2(Derived1):
    pass

class Derived3(Derived2):
    def method(self):
        # …
```

The problem: I would like to somehow define `method` in `Derived3` so that it calls itself from `Base`.

Normally I would just write:

```
class Derived3(Derived2):
    super().method()
```

But this would call `method` from `Derived1`, which is exactly what I want to avoid. I want to call `method` from `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly call a member of the superclass, simply passing `self` as the first argument:

```
Base.method(self)
```

Complete example:

```
class Derived3(Derived2):
    def method(self):
        Base.method(self)
```

This will execute `Base.method` on the instance specified by `self`, which is passed to `Derived3.method` automatically when it is accessed [through an instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#methods).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to call the `Base` method directly, passing `self` explicitly:

```
Base.method(self)
```

If the goal is to skip to "whatever is after some known bad super class in the MRO" though, you can use `super` with explicit arguments to act as if it was called from the "bad super class" so it moves to "whatever comes next":

```
class Derived3(Derived2):
    def method(self):
        # Call method from next class after Derived1 in MRO, which happens to be Base
        # Using super means the method is bound, so self passed implicitly to method
        super(Derived1, self).method()
```